# Show that $\det(\text{tr}(u_iu_j))=c^2\det(\text{tr}(v_iv_j))$ for some $c\in k^{\times}$, where $u,v$ are basis of a $k$-algebra of finite dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a $k$-algebra of finite dimension.
For each $a\in A$, define the trace $\text{tr}(a)$ as the trace of the matrix of the endomorphism $x\mapsto ax$.
Define $B(u,v)=\text{tr}(uv)$,
which can be shown to be a $k$-bilinear form.
Now, suppose $\{u_j\}$ and $\{v_j\}$ are two $k$-bases of $A$.
Define the matrices $M_{ij}=B(u_i,u_j)$ and $N_{ij}=B(v_i,v_j)$.
I would like to show that there exists $c\in k^{\times}$ such that $\det(M)=c^2\det(N)$.

I tried writing
$$
u_i=\sum_k a_{ik}v_k
$$
and
$$
B(u_i,u_j)=\sum_{k,l} a_{ik}a_{jl} B(v_k,v_l).
$$
Using the Leibniz formula for determinant does not seem viable.
Is there any property of the trace form that I missed?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is to realize that the RHS of the formula $B(u_i,u_j)=\sum_{k,l} a_{ik}a_{jl} B(v_k,v_l)$ defines a triple product of matrices, namely if we denote $A=(a_{ji})$, then $A^tB(u_i,u_j)A=B(v_i,v_j)$. Now just take determinants of both sides.

All of this works for any bilinear form, not just the trace form.